# Why doesn't twill show a form?

Tags: twill

I am trying to access a website using twill: https://cuentas.itesm.mx/IDMProv/portal/cn/GuestContainerPage/ITESMPageForgotPassword

On the website code there is this field that I need to fill `personID`, inside the form `frmChRIndex`

```html
<form id="frmChRIndex" name="frmChRIndex" action="validaUsuario.htm" method="POST">
    <div class="clearFields">
     <div class="label-info">
   Usuario (A00000000 / L00000000)(*)
  </div>
     <div class="field-info">
   <input type="text" name="personId" id="personId" value="" maxlength="9"                       onblur="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();">
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

When I use the command `showforms` on twill, this form does not appear.

It returns these forms

```
  Form #1
## ## __Name__________________ __Type___ __ID________ __Value__________________
1     login                    hidden    (None)       login 
2     uasess                   hidden    (None)       -4301763981694819540 


Form name=nav__NVL354063pageLinkForm (#2)
## ## __Name__________________ __Type___ __ID________ __Value__________________
1     navUrl                   hidden    (None)       /IDMProv/portal/cn/GuestContainerPag ... 
2     uasess                   hidden    (None)       -4301763981694819540 


Form name=nav__NVL354063pageLinkForm (#3)
## ## __Name__________________ __Type___ __ID________ __Value__________________
1     navUrl                   hidden    (None)       /IDMProv/portal/cn/GuestContainerPag ... 
2     uasess                   hidden    (None)       -4301763981694819540 


Form name=nav__NVL354063pageLinkForm (#4)
## ## __Name__________________ __Type___ __ID________ __Value__________________
1     navUrl                   hidden    (None)       /IDMProv/portal/cn/GuestContainerPag ... 
2     uasess                   hidden    (None)       -4301763981694819540 


Form name=nav__NVL354063pageLinkForm (#5)
## ## __Name__________________ __Type___ __ID________ __Value__________________
1     navUrl                   hidden    (None)       /IDMProv/portal/cn/GuestContainerPag ... 
2     uasess                   hidden    (None)       -4301763981694819540 


Form name=nav__NVL354063pageLinkForm (#6)
## ## __Name__________________ __Type___ __ID________ __Value__________________
1     navUrl                   hidden    (None)       /IDMProv/portal/cn/GuestContainerPag ... 
2     uasess                   hidden    (None)       -4301763981694819540 


Form name=nav__NVL354063pageLinkForm (#7)
## ## __Name__________________ __Type___ __ID________ __Value__________________
1     navUrl                   hidden    (None)       /IDMProv/portal/cn/GuestContainerPag ... 
2     uasess                   hidden    (None)       -4301763981694819540 


Form name=nav__NVL354063pageLinkForm (#8)
## ## __Name__________________ __Type___ __ID________ __Value__________________
1     navUrl                   hidden    (None)       /IDMProv/portal/cn/GuestContainerPag ... 
2     uasess                   hidden    (None)       -4301763981694819540
```

Any ideas on why is this happening?